# QGIS Identify tool Browse button not working

Tags: qgis, identify, photos, browser

I am trying to add photo files to specific points in QGIS 2.18  using the instructions found in the training manual section 6.4 
https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html.

I have followed the direction exactly and created a field for images.  The problem is that when I try to add the file to the image field under filename  I can see the browse button but clicking it does not open a file browsing dialogue.  It does nothing.

Is there another way to specify my file path or another way to add non-geotagged photos to specific points?

Answer (score 1):

I have just reproduced the procedure and I completed the §6.4.2 without any problem. Maybe, the browse button was not clickable since you weren't in the edit mode:

[image]

Instead, enabling the edit mode will lead you to edit the filepath for the image:

[image]

Comment: Nope.  In edit mode the button still does nothing.

Comment: @JoMurphy I think you should add more context to your original question in order to attract more detailed answers, since it is unclear what does not work. For example, you may explain where are you precisely stuck (attaching image would be appreciated).

Comment: I get to the last image except the image field says" NULL" (but is not greyed out) and clicking the browse button causes the ok button to flash (blue to gray to blue once) but does not open a file selection dialogue window. I am definitely in edit mode.

Comment: I am running Qgis 2.18 on mac 10.11